# How to fire an event when v-model changes?

Tags: javascript, events, vue.js

I'm trying to fire the `foo()` function with the `@click` but as you can see, need press the radio button two times to fire the event correctly . Only catch the value the second time that you press...

I want to fire the event without `@click` only fire the event when `v-model` (srStatus) changes.

here is my Fiddle:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/wanxe/vsa46bw8/

Comment: fiddle link is no longer working.

Comment: If the intent of calling `foo()` is to make non template changes, use a `watcher`

Comment: This is a great example of why code is required _in the question_. Please recover it if possible and show it here.

Comment: I wish I could retrieve the code for the question, but it was 5 years ago already... luckily we have good answers

Answer (score 109, accepted):

This happens because your `click` handler fires before the value of the radio button changes. You need to listen to the `change` event instead:

```
<input 
  type="radio" 
  name="optionsRadios" 
  id="optionsRadios2" 
  value=""
  v-model="srStatus" 
  v-on:change="foo"> //here
```

Also, make sure you really want to call `foo()` on ready... seems like maybe you don't actually want to do that.

```
ready:function(){
    foo();
},
```

Comment: How would you handle Sliders?

Comment: where are the available events listed in the documentation. I can't find it?

Comment: These are just standard JavaScript events which you can find here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events#Standard_events

Comment: Thanks! But Ready:function didn't work for me. Instead, methods:{ foo(){//do something} }

Comment: Also note that if you want to register "v-on:change" events on a custom vue component (single file component), "v-on:input" should be used instead.

Answer (score 124):

You can actually simplify this by removing the `v-on` directives:

```
<input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="1" v-model="srStatus">
```

And use the `watch` method to listen for the change:

```
new Vue ({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        cases: [
            { name: 'case A', status: '1' },
            { name: 'case B', status: '0' },
            { name: 'case C', status: '1' }
        ],
        activeCases: [],
        srStatus: ''
    },
    watch: {
        srStatus: function(val, oldVal) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.cases.length; i++) {
                if (this.cases[i].status == val) {
                    this.activeCases.push(this.cases[i]);
                    alert("Fired! " + val);
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you watch automatically any model change ? For example for a form with multiple inputs that all needs to be watched ?

Comment: @EricBurel I know this is old, but the answer is no.  You can't watch the entire data object all the fields are bound to, you would need to watch each and every single property of that object individually making this approach problematic for big records on forms with a lot of fields.

Comment: @EricBurel Actually you can watch nested objects with the 'deep' property set to 'true' --> https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#watch

Answer (score 50):

You should use `@input`:

```
<input @input="handleInput" />
```

`@input` fires when user changes input value.

`@change` fires when user changed value and unfocus input (for example clicked somewhere outside)

You can see the difference here: https://jsfiddle.net/posva/oqe9e8pb/

Comment: [vue 2 doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html)  [vue 3 doc](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/forms.html)

Comment: For text input ``@input`` and for other types of controls like <select> and checkbox ``@change`` works best.

Answer (score 41):

**Vue2:** if you only want to detect change on input blur (e.g. after press enter or click somewhere else) do (more info [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html))

```
<input @change="foo" v-model... >
```

If you wanna detect single character changes (during user typing) use

```
<input @keydown="foo" v-model... >
```

You can also use `@keyup` and `@input` events. If you wanna to pass additional parameters use in template e.g.  `@keyDown="foo($event, param1, param2)"`. Comparision below (editable version [here](https://jsfiddle.net/josLq1af/1/))

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: { 
    keyDown: { key:null, val: null,  model: null, modelCopy: null },
    keyUp: { key:null, val: null,  model: null, modelCopy: null },
    change: { val: null,  model: null, modelCopy: null },
    input: { val: null,  model: null, modelCopy: null },
    
    
  },
  methods: {
  
    keyDownFun: function(event){                   // type of event: KeyboardEvent   
      console.log(event);  
      this.keyDown.key = event.key;                // or event.keyCode
      this.keyDown.val = event.target.value;       // html current input value
      this.keyDown.modelCopy = this.keyDown.model; // copy of model value at the moment on event handling
    },
    
    keyUpFun: function(event){                     // type of event: KeyboardEvent
      console.log(event);  
      this.keyUp.key = event.key;                  // or event.keyCode
      this.keyUp.val = event.target.value;         // html current input value
      this.keyUp.modelCopy = this.keyUp.model;     // copy of model value at the moment on event handling
    },
    
    changeFun: function(event) {                   // type of event: Event
      console.log(event);
      this.change.val = event.target.value;        // html current input value
      this.change.modelCopy = this.change.model;   // copy of model value at the moment on event handling
    },
    
    inputFun: function(event) {                    // type of event: Event
      console.log(event);
      this.input.val = event.target.value;         // html current input value
      this.input.modelCopy = this.input.model;     // copy of model value at the moment on event handling
    }
  }
})
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

Type in fields below (to see events details open browser console)

<div id="app">
  <div><input type="text" @keyDown="keyDownFun" v-model="keyDown.model"><br> @keyDown (note: model is different than value and modelCopy)<br> key:{{keyDown.key}}<br> value: {{ keyDown.val }}<br> modelCopy: {{keyDown.modelCopy}}<br> model: {{keyDown.model}}</div>
  
  <div><input type="text" @keyUp="keyUpFun" v-model="keyUp.model"><br> @keyUp (note: model change value before event occure) <br> key:{{keyUp.key}}<br> value: {{ keyUp.val }}<br> modelCopy: {{keyUp.modelCopy}}<br> model: {{keyUp.model}}</div>
  
  <div><input type="text" @change="changeFun" v-model="change.model"><br> @change (occures on enter key or focus change (tab, outside mouse click) etc.)<br> value: {{ change.val }}<br> modelCopy: {{change.modelCopy}}<br> model: {{change.model}}</div>
  
  <div><input type="text" @input="inputFun" v-model="input.model"><br> @input<br> value: {{ input.val }}<br> modelCopy: {{input.modelCopy}}<br> model: {{input.model}}</div>
     
</div>
```

Comment: keyDown not working than 'backspace' pressed. So it is better to use @input

Comment: In this fiddle we see that backspace works with `@keyDown` https://jsfiddle.net/rLzm0f1q/ (however I don't say that `@input` is bad or good)

Comment: I want to add that when using keyDown, the model only seems to update after the event fires. When using input, it seems to update before.

Answer (score 10):

Just to add to the correct answer above, in Vue.JS v1.0 you can write

```
<a v-on:click="doSomething">
```

So in this example it would be

```
 v-on:change="foo"
```

See: http://v1.vuejs.org/guide/syntax.html#Arguments