# v-on:change not calling method in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

This seems like a simple thing to do so I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong here, I followed this question [how to fire an event when v-model changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257379/how-to-fire-an-event-when-v-model-changes-vue-js)

but I cant seem to get it to work..

This is my component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm" v-on:change="search" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
   data() {
       return {
           searchTerm: ''
       }
   },
   methods: {
       search() {
           console.log(this.searchTerm);
       }
   }
}
</script>
```

now basically what I'm trying to do is when a user starts typing in the input, fire this event and `console.log()` the updated searchTerm, but when I start typing nothing is logged to the console??

Am I doing something wrong? Is this not how you listen to v-model changes in nuxt?

Comment: did you try `v-on:input` ?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim yes that worked! thankyou

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `@input` instead of `@change` event like so :

```
  <template>
     <div>
          <input type="text" v-model="searchTerm" v-on:input="search" />
     </div>
  </template>
```